# How to take back delegated CPU or NET amounts?

Tags: staking

Let's assume there's two account A, B. Here is A and B's current status.

A

- staked : 10 EOS
- delegated : 0 EOS
- balance : 100 EOS

B

- staked : 10 EOS
- delegated : 0 EOS
- balance : 100 EOS

(For convenience, I only described CPU.)

First, A typed command like below,

`cleos system delegatebw A B "0.0000 EOS" "10.0000 EOS" --transfer`

So, changes happen.

A

- staked : 10 EOS
- delegated : 0 EOS

  **- balance : 90 EOS**

B

**- staked : 20 EOS**

- delegated : 0 EOS
- balance : 100 EOS

And, Second command is below.

`cleos system undelegatebw B B "0.0000 EOS" "10.0000 EOS"`

Because of this command, B's status will be changed like below. (After 3 days)

B

**- staked : 10 EOS**

- delegated : 0 EOS

  **- balance : 110 EOS**

Third command is below.

`cleos system delegatebw A B "0.0000 EOS" "10.0000 EOS"`
(without --transfer option)

Changes happen again.

A

- staked : 10 EOS
- delegated : 0 EOS

  **- balance : 80 EOS**

A

- staked : 10 EOS

  **- delegated : 10 EOS**
- balance : 110 EOS

My questions is..
How can B take back his 10 EOS which used in Third command? In my thought, if an account has only staked values, when typed "cleos system undelegatebw A A (amount)", It goes into A's liquid balances. But I can't figure out how to to with delegated amounts.

It will be grateful if you answer with cleos command!

Comment: If you don't use --transfer, only the delegated one can get the EOS back, in your example, it's A, without transfer, the EOS is still belong to A.

Comment: @KemmyGuo So In this situation (which eos is still belong to A), how to A take back his EOS which he delegate to B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B delegated to A without transfer, and B wants their stake back:

```
cleos wallet unlock -n walletwithactivekeyforaccountB
```

> (enter related password to unlock wallet)

```
cleos system undelegatebw B A "0.0000 EOS" "10.0000 EOS" -p B@active
```

BOOM! That's It! But it is not instant! By design, it will take 3 days to unstake.

Comment: If the way this is supposed to work is that after 3 days the undelegated amount moves to the EOS balance and is then available for withdrawl to an exchange, then can you please explain why after I undelegated some EOS several weeks ago, it is still sitting in the "net" field and never moved automatically to the EOS field after 3 days had passed? Is there another step I have to make to make it transfer if it doesn't happen automatically? It has been stuck in the "NET" (3 day pending) category for something like 2 or 3 months now. Thank You

Comment: Oh and I tried the refund fallback option as well, and got a failure message with this data...

Comment: {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3050003,
    "name": "eosio_assert_message_exception",
    "what": "eosio_assert_message assertion failure",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "assertion failure with message: refund request not found",
        "file": "wasm_interface.cpp",
        "line_number": 924,
        "method": "eosio_assert"
      },
      {
        "message": "pending console output: ",
        "file": "apply_context.cpp",
        "line_number": 72,
        "method": "exec_one"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please open a new question so that we can help you more efficiently!

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do with Scatter and EOS Tool Kit!!!

1. When staking EOS for CPU and Bandwidth for another account, make sure the transfer button is off. This ensures you retain staking control.
2. Go to Undelegate (Unstake) section under Manage Account Tab 
   https://eostoolkit.io/account/undelegate
3. Stake Owner is your original account from which you staked.
4. Stake Holder is the account for which you had staked.
5. Enter the the amount of EOS to unstake and sign the transaction with Scatter ... and voila you are done!!!

Special Thanks to Nathan Rempel from GenerEOS and EOS toolkit who helped answer this question.